# French equivalents of "some people", as in "Honestly, some people!"

Tags: anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, allemand, espagnol

To express the idea of "*Honestly, **some people**!*" (said irritatedly), in conversation I said jokingly:

> Tu ne sais pas que c’est mal élevé d’interrompre une conversation ? Franchement, **il y a de ces gens** !

I wonder though if this phrasing gets across the meaning well enough, or for that matter, if it is commonly used.

While the translation of "*some people ... (others)*" is as straightforward as they come, when it comes to this specific usage, there's more to it than meets the eye.

In German and Spanish, for instance, idiomatic phrasings for this are "*Also wirklich, **Leute gibt’s**!*" and "*¡Desde luego, **qué gente**!*" -- in a similar vein, to be sure, but with a slightly different flavour.

Comment: In a casual speech, your expression is alright; I personnally say "y a des gens" and even "y a des mecs" pretty often. Note however that this is very informal .

Comment: By the way, "Je te jure/J'te jure" could be used in lieu of "franchement"

Comment: Brel would have said 'ces gens-là'.

Answer (score 5):

> Franchement, **y'en a, j'te dis pas !**

Comment: A bit longer, but in a similar tone, I'd also have said: "*Comme malpoli, tu te poses là !*", "*On a déjà vu mieux comme manières !*", "*On a vu mieux en matière d'éducation !*". What's your take on them?

Comment: *Comme malpoli, tu te poses là* is a direct (and possibly rude) remark to the person you are talking to while *Y'en a, j'te dis pas* or *qué gente* are generic remarks. They normally target someone else than the person you are talking to but can nevertheless be used indirectly.

Comment: What does "en" mean in "y en a" (a usual informal reduction of "il y en a") ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista *En* refers to what/who we are talking about. In the OP question context, that would be *des gens* (people), i.e. *Y'en a, des gens, j'te dis pas comment qu'y sont malpolis*: an apophasis (*prétérition*) with a very relaxed grammar...

Answer (score 2):

As for "Honestly, some people!" (said irritatedly), I would like to throw

> Ah, les gens !

into the ring. Not because it's better than the other renditions, but because it's closer to the original. As above, you may add "j'te jure" ("I'm telling ya.") or any equivalent amplifier for effect.

Selected web-search results:

- [BirdsDessinés: Ah les gens](https://www.birdsdessines.fr/2018/02/06/ah-les-gens/)
- [aufeminin.Suisse: Ah, les gens, je vous jure...](https://psychologie.aufeminin.com/forum/ah-les-gens-je-vous-jure-fd573380)